# Retrieving query dry run statistics

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am attempting to run a simple example for a query. However, I would like to be able to first have a dry run of the query to retrieve the processing size required. The way this will ultimately work is that a bunch of queries will be run and I am trying to first get an estimate of the total costs. Basically, I would like to have access to the same info you see when the query is validated in the UI and it tells you e.g., "this query will process 6.5GB of data".

[image]

Now, I can run my query fine and retrieve its results without any issues:

```
def get_event_data(client, pj, start_range, end_range, debug = False, dryRun = True):
    query = '''#legacySQL
            SELECT type FROM (
            TABLE_DATE_RANGE([data_archive:day.], 
                TIMESTAMP(\'{0}\'), 
                TIMESTAMP(\'{1}\') 
              ))
            WHERE pj.name = \'{2}\' '''.format(start_range, end_range, project)


    if (debug):
        print(query)


    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.use_legacy_sql = True
    job_config.dryRun = dryRun
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config = job_config)
    results = query_job.result()

    rows = list(results)

    print(len(rows))
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

But, what I can't figure out in the API docs is where I can get that processing info... Since I use the python client, I am not forming my own requests and do not seem to receive the http response where this info might be stored. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated, I haven't been able to access this info just yet :(

Cheers,

Greg

Comment: I believe you are referring to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) documentation to setup your query configuration. You should instead be referring [this](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#run-a-dry-run-query) documentation.

Comment: Indeed, although this was not available in the docs back when I was looking it up. Good thing it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were close but instead of `dryRun` you should set `dry_run=True` in the `QueryJobConfig` object:

```
query_config.dry_run = True
query_config.use_legacy_sql = True
job = client.query(query, job_config=query_config)
print("Total bytes that will be processed: ", job.total_bytes_processed)
print("Bytes billed: ", job.total_bytes_billed)
```

This behavior happens in the latest version of the Google Cloud API so to give users greater flexibility on what they can define for the query job (I think this was a request from BigQuery's backend team as this allows them to create new features that can be used without the need of source code deployment).

And as a side note, I'd recommend using the [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) version instead of legacy, it's way more powerful and stable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Mind you I have been able to work around this ubing bq query which does report it using the dry run parameter. However, the doc mentions that dryRun should be spelled the way I did, plus I got no error when I did that (using a random property name does raise an error).

In any case I will give that a shot thanks!

(re: the use of legacySQL: thanks, I'm new to BigQuery and haven't figured out how to use table wildcards in standardSQL for my use case. I've tried but have run in issues so far. It's definitely something I'm considering for the future though)

Comment: Just tried it with dry_run and it works, thanks a bunch!

For those interested, that value is is query_job.total_bytes_processed.